# how to configure cypress-sql-server to be used in different environments prod and dev

Tags: testing, plugins, cypress

I'm using cypress-sql-server plugin to be configured based on different environments for production.json and development.json

```
{
"env": {
"userName":"sa",
"password": "",
"server": "localhost",
"port": "1433",
"options": {
"database": "TestDatabase",
"encrypt": true,
"rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion" : true
}
}
}

the index.js file in the plugins

const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs-extra");
const sqlServer = require('cypress-sql-server');

function getConfigurationByFile(file) {
const pathToConfigFile = path.resolve("cypress/config", ${file}.json)
console.error('the server path',pathToConfigFile)
return fs.readJson(pathToConfigFile);
}

module.exports = async (on, config) => {
tasks = sqlServer.loadDBPlugin(config);
on('task', tasks);
const file = config.env.fileConfig
return getConfigurationByFile(file)
}
```

when I run the test case I get the failure message as below

`cy.task('sqlServer:execute')`  failed with the following error:

Invalid server: undefined"

I replace localhost with machine name, but same error.I think `sqlServer.loadDBPlugin(config)` is not getting right data.
Any idea guys?

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: cypress is configured in package. json  "cypress": "cypress open --env fileConfig=development"   development.json = `{   "env": {
      "db": {
        "userName": "sa",
        "password": "",
        "server": "localhost",
        "port": "1433",
        "options": {
            "database": "TestDatabase",
            "encrypt": true,
            "rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion" : true
        }                                                                       
    }
  }
}` Still same issue

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and replaced the cypress-sql-server with the tedious one directly. Using these:
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/6621

Note: install the fixed version:

> "coffeescript": "^2.5.1",
> "tedious": "^ 8.3.0"

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify that in your cypress.json or other configuration file like so?

> Your cypress.json (or environment specific files in the config
> directory) should specify the DB redentials in the following format
>
> ```
> "db": {
>     "userName": "",
>     "password": "",
>     "server": "",
>     "options": {
>         "database": "",
>         "encrypt": true,
>         "rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion" : true
>     }
> }
> ```

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-sql-server